# Make bot automatically quit after it has done its work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'd like to use my bot not as a daemon that runs forever, but as a kind of "shell script". So it should automatically quit after it has done its work.

My approach so far in Python 3.5 / Python 3.6:

```
import discord
TOKEN = '<redacted>'
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for member in client.get_all_members():
        print(member.display_name)
    # please, please quit now!

client.run(TOKEN)
```

What I want here is, that the script should just quit after printing all the members' display_names, so I can further process them elsewhere. At the moment it DOES print the desired information, but continues to run forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question myself:

Just replace the line `# please, please quit now!` with `await client.logout()` does the job.